# My WordPress site got updated and also few plugins. site is not loading any more. What i can do it to win it back

Tags: php, wordpress

I have WordPress site and it is updated new version. I don't know how. Few plugins also got updated. Now sites page is not loading. Server is working fine but pages are loading.

I don't have back up. How should I get back the things.

[image]

Comment: In case no errors show on the screen, you could have a look at the error.log of php to see what breaks the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to learn your lesson about backups. Always have a backup.

It's most likely that one plugin is breaking your site. You can copy the /wp-content folder of your site to your computer using FTP and then (after copying it locally!), one by one, delete the plugin folders in wp-content/plugins themselves on your site over FTP. After deleting each plugin folder, check if your site is back up.
If you find the offending plugin, try reinstalling it through the WordPress admin panel. Because you deleted the plugin folder and not the database entries, the settings **should** still be there, but your local copy is in case of further emergency anyway.

Comment: i got lesson but this was so cruel, 9 months work n one click. will disabling the plugins one after one will have same effect? @Kinna T

Comment: Wordpress can be a cruel mistress.  Yes, if you can access the WordPress admin area, it would have the same effect.  Consider yourself lucky if the admin area works!

Comment: When I disable site origin builder bludle theme. Site show up but all broken. I tried reinstalling site origin builder same problem arises....

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming your plugin folders via FTP connection. Do that one-by-one and reload the site each time. They will be deactivated after you do this, and you will find the plugin which is causing the problem.